# Finding all the values of a and b such that T is an isomophism?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T(f)=f^{''}+af^{'}+bf$ is the transformation. V is the space spanned by cos(t) and sin(t).

Comment: On what space does this act? Polynomials with real coefficients?

Comment: it's for cos(t) and sin(t).

Answer (score 0):

Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{\cos{t},\sin{t}\}$ and find the matrix's determinant.